# Paypal Custom Auto Return payment success URL for app wise transaction

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I'am trying to deploy an app on Autodesk appstore.
Appstore accepts only PalPay account email as payment signature, so for payment verification steps involve  adding Autodesk Success page URL for payment confirmation validation in PayPal account Auto return settings section.

So my query is can we set an auto return payment success URL for a transaction those are through Autodesk product page in PayPal Business Account Setting section itself , and other transaction should redirect to my page.

I have been exploring the same, and looking for a solution that can be most optimal,
Following are the 2 things that are into consideration as of now:
1] To host a page which will parse the payment notification, and then redirect to respective URL.
2] Set up a dedicated account in PayPal for Appstore transactions.

I have these 2 options, but trying to find out if we can apply a redirect rule in PayPal Account setting itself

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

> Appstore accepts only PayPal account email as payment signature, so for payment verification steps involve adding Autodesk Success page URL for payment confirmation validation in PayPal account Auto return settings section.

The Auto Return configured in the PayPal account is a legacy setting for PayPal/Website Payment Standard integrations, which use no API to set up the payment and are very old. Autodesk might be using such an integration, but it is also possible they are using an API and passing a `subject` or `payee` parameter with the email address. If they are, the Auto Return setting in the PayPal account will have no effect.

Furthermore, even if Autodesk is using the old no-API Payments Standard, it is possible they are setting [a "return" variable](https://developer.paypal.com/api/nvp-soap/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx-websitestandard-htmlvariables/#link-paypalcheckoutpagevariables) at initial redirect-to-PayPal time with their own return URL, which will be used in place of any account setting.

Furthermore, with no-API Payments Standard transactions there is never any guarantee that the payer will actually return to the specified URL after transaction completion. Any number of things can prevent them from returning, for example PayPal may be obligated to show them a recepit for legal reasons and they need to manually click to return and choose not to do so, or their browser crashes or does not successfully return after transaction completion for whatever reason.

Therefore, the old Payments Standard return should never be relied on for anything of any importance (for example notifying your system of successful payment completion, or order fulfillment. It is useless and should never be relied on for this purpose.)